# iOS PhoneGap 1.0 Plugins not being found using XCode 4

Tags: iphone, plugins, xcode4, cordova

I'm trying to install the ChildBrowser with XCode 4 to PhoneGap 1.0.  I'm not sure why I'm getting these errors after I have inserted the information into the Plugin folder and PhoneGap.plist.  I only get these following errors and I'm stuck.  Any ideas on what I should try out?

2011-08-26 14:51:18.841 USCTSP[10359:f503] PGPlugin class ChildBrowserCommand (pluginName: ChildBrowserCommand) does not exist.
2011-08-26 14:51:18.842 USCTSP[10359:f503] ERROR: Plugin 'ChildBrowserCommand' not found, or is not a PGPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in PhoneGap.plist.

This error occurs after I attempt to load the childBrowser.  The only reason I think its not just childBrowser is because my GoogleAnalyticsPlugin is not working as well.  It throws the same error.  I don't think I installed it properly.  However, I must be missing something.  I am running the latest builds as well.

**UPDATE**:

I found my own answer.  Its because I selected "*reference*" instead of "*group*".

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/41733808/PhoneGap%20iOS%20Plugins%20Problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my own answer. Its because I selected "reference" instead of "group".

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/41733808/PhoneGap%20iOS%20Plugins%20Problems